# USB Wifi DW130 not recognized in Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, usb-modem

I purchased a D Link DW130 USB WiFi modem and cannot get it recognized in Ubuntu.  I am very PC knowledgeable but have just installed Ubuntu for the first time this morning.  Can anyone help me to configure this modem in Ubuntu?

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2001:3c25 D-Link Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Which tells me that it is recognized by the system but the OS does not recognize or allow me to configure it.

Comment: What's the output of `lsusb`?

Comment: I edited my original question to include the output  @ron

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: yes  Ubuntu 104.04 LTS as per the "about this computer" screen

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps:

1.In the terminal type:

`sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/network_drivers.conf`

2. Add the following in a single line:

   `install rt2800usb /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install rt2800usb $CMDLINE_OPTS; /bin/echo "2001 3c25" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rt2800usb/new_id`

to the file.

3. `sudo modprobe rt2800usb`
4. Reboot

Post back if you are experiencing any problems.

Comment: I think I'm a little lost.  When I input the line "sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/network_drivers.conf" in terminal I get a screen that is different from what I have seen before.  I'm not sure how to paste screen shots to here.  If you tell me how I will paste it and then hopefully we can get this thing running.  @Ron

Comment: upload the screenshot in services like [this](http://imgur.com/) and share the link

Comment: http://imgur.com/WFZBk4G  Let me know if that worked.

Comment: yeah, now press `ctrl+o`, press `enter` to save and then `ctrl+x` to exit `nano`. Continue with the rest of the steps.

Comment: Ok done.  no errors with the code but no wireless network option possible.  see attached.  FYI my phone is connected to my house wifi as I speak so I know the Wifi is working.  http://imgur.com/wPRAhsT

Comment: Is there a way to scan for networks like Windows or does it need to be setup manually

Comment: Maybe @Chili555 could help